# Proc Tabulate won't honor order=data option

Tags: sas

I'm using `proc tabulate` to export a some data that is already sorted in a particular way, and I'm using the `order=data` option to preserve the starting order.  However SAS isn't cooperating.  See the contrived example below:

Program:

```
data d1;
    input var1 $ var2 $ var3;
    datalines;
e j 1
e k 2
e l 3
b n 1
b k 2
b l 3
b j 4
b m 5
a n 1
a m 2
a l 3
;
run;

proc tabulate order=data;
    class var1 var2;
    var var3;
    table var1*var2, var3;
run;
```

Output:

```
            var3     
            Sum      
var1  var2           
e     j         1.00 
      k         2.00 
      l         3.00 
b     j         4.00 
      k         2.00 
      l         3.00 
      n         1.00 
      m         5.00 
a     l         3.00 
      n         1.00 
      m         2.00
```

As you can see, var2 and var3 have been re-orded in the second and third var1 groups.  It appears that it's sticking to the order in the first var1 as much a possible.

I'm just using `tabulate` for cosmetic purposes would like to completely stop if from shuffling things.  Does anyone know how I make it behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS is doing exactly what it says it's doing: it's ordering them by the order they're in the dataset.

It doesn't order them by the *joint* order, though, that's not how the proc works internally.  It's setting up a crosstab, not just printing out numbers (which you are basically using it for, and sometimes that's fine, but not for this purpose).  SAS doesn't know ahead of time that only some `var2` show up in a particular `var1`.

I would use `proc report` if you're trying to just print it out nicely, that will behave itself more like what you expect.  Or even `proc print`.

You also could create a format that had separate values for every single row, formatting them to display as they are, but actually underlying the value is a number (that's built such that the lowest number is the top row on the table to highest number is bottom row for that section on the table).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and is consistent with my vague suspicions.  I still hope that someone might know a little trick to override this logical behavior (it wouldn't be the first time).  In the meantime I'm focusing on making `proc report` conform to my needs.

Comment: The trick I  mention above is the only one I can imagine working - it's not impossible to do, and I've done it before for other reasons.